# How can I fix those issues generated by the Themecheck plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, shortcode, errors, register-taxonomy

I've got the following error messages on the themecheck plugin in my WordPress theme.

> REQUIRED: The theme uses the register_taxonomy() function, which is plugin-territory functionality. 
>   REQUIRED: The theme uses the register_post_type() function, which is plugin-territory functionality. 
>   WARNING: The theme uses the add_shortcode() function. Custom post-content shortcodes are plugin-territory functionality.

I declared the `register_taxonomy()` and `register_post_type()` function in `after_setup_theme` hook. 
My `register_taxonomy()` function is:

```
register_taxonomy('project_cat', 'project', array(
    'public'        => true,
    'hierarchical'  => true,
    'labels'        => array(
        'name'  => 'Categories',
    )
));
```

And one of my `register_post_type()` function is:

```
register_post_type('service', array(
    'public'    => true,
    'supports'  => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'editor'),
    'labels'    => array(
        'name'          => esc_html__('Services', 'textdomain'),
        'add_new_item'  => esc_html__('Add Service', 'textdomain'),
        'add_new'       => esc_html__('Add Service', 'textdomain')
    )
));
```

How can I fix those issues?

Comment: The messages are pretty clear. What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Registering custom posts is a plugin territory. It means that you need to remove them from the theme's functionality and register them via a plugin (usually recommended when installing the theme using [TGM Plugin Activation](http://tgmpluginactivation.com/) or something else). [Here are the recommendations](https://make.wordpress.org/themes/handbook/guidelines/plugin-territory/) of the Theme Review Team.

> Themes must not incorporate the following, Plugin-territory
>   functionality. This list is not all-inclusive.
>
> - Analytics scripts
> - SEO options (meta tags, page title, post titles, robots.txt, etc.)
> - Content Sharing buttons/links
> - Custom post-content shortcodes
> - Custom Post Types
> - Custom Taxonomies
> - Removing or modifying non-presentational core hooks
> - Disabling the admin toolbar
> - Resource compression/caching

Answer (score 4):

You should reread the error messages. Custom taxonomies, custom post types and shortcodes should **not** be registered in a theme, that should be standard practice. Custom taxonomies, custom post types and shortcodes shoule be registered in a plugin.